# Questions about working conditions

Tags: discussion

I want to ask a question about *props&cons of standing at work*, but I'm not sure if it really fits into "freelancing" topic.

Is it appropriate to ask questions like this: questions about working conditions, different "life-hack", "work-from-home" techniques, tips and tricks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally, I think [Workplace.SE](http://workplace.stackexchange.com) (also in beta) would be an ideal place for working condition questions, if only the question really fit there, which would mean on-site contracted work or something similar.

However, this is for self-employed and freelancing people, so the questions of *responsibility* for workplace grievances when on-site would be fine here. As would be freelancing from home (as a lot of web developers do).

Moreover, please don't ask "Pros and Cons" (list-type) questions on the Stack Exchange network. We like expert-level, specific questions (heck, we live on them here), and they are warned against in the beta email you received.